# How to reliably send tracking event on link click?

Tags: javascript

I have a tracking event (in the form of an http call to a tracking server) that fires on the clicking of a link, fired by an onclick event.

However, it appears that fairly often, the event is not registered by the tracking server because the browser cuts off the (long-running) event call when it loads the new page.

I'm reluctant to wait for a reply before forwarding the user to the new page, in case the reply is delayed and the user has to wait.

Is there a way to ensure the event call completes and forward the user on immediately?

Comment: Nope.  There isn't even a way to ensure that the event call is made at all.  The user can just go to the next page without notifying the tracking event.

Comment: **Please, try sharing the code.** Although, maybe if you only `return true` when - I'm guessing - form be submited, it will 'wait' for the event. Otherwise, you may have to use some httprequests or ajax. I don't see how can you track the event after the loading of another page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `preventDefault` helps you. You don't share your code, it's because I explain you this way:

```
 $('a.link').on('click', function(e) {

     e.preventDefault();
     var trackingLink = $(this).attr('href');
     // do ajax stuff
     $.ajax().success(function() {
          window.location.href = trackingLink;
     });

 });
```

With `preventDefault()` you avoid links to load the page, then make the ajax requests and if it's successful redirects to the page of the link

Answer (score 0):

One option is to end an 'unload' event handler, and send the data it the handler. This will delay the unload of the page.

Example:

```
$(window).on('unload', function() {
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "serverUrl",
      data: { logData: '....' }
    })
});
```

Maybe you can use the `.sendBeacon` method. It's only supported by Chrome and Firefox right now, but the description from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) seems to fit you needs:

> This method addresses the needs of analytics and diagnostics code that
>   typically attempt to send data to a web server prior to the unloading
>   of the document.

Example (from the MDN article):

```
window.addEventListener('unload', logData, false);

function logData() {
    navigator.sendBeacon("/log", analyticsData);
}
```